# Feeds Api conditionally skip deletion of terms

Tags: entities, feeds

I have a taxonomy vocabulary of customer addresses as terms that I maintain via the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. Most of the terms will be added via the Feeds import, however I want users to have the ability to add an address term to the vocabulary and not have those particular user added terms deleted when feeds does an import (feeds should still remove terms that aren't marked as user created if they're not in the imported CSV file)

**Is there a way in Feeds API to skip deletion of terms that have a particular field value?**

Thanks